# Prevent mgo/bson Unmarshal to clear unexported fields

Tags: mongodb, go, unmarshalling, mgo

I try to populate the exported fields of a struct with content fetched from a [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org)-database using the [labix.org/v2/mgo](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo) package.

`mgo` uses the [labix.org/v2/mgo/bson](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson) package to unmarshal the data. But the unmarshaller sets all unexported fields to their zero value.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

type Sub struct{ Int int }

type Player struct {
    Name       string
    unexpInt   int
    unexpPoint *Sub
}

func main() {
    dta,err := bson.Marshal(bson.M{"name": "ANisus"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    p := &Player{unexpInt: 12, unexpPoint: &Sub{42}}

    fmt.Printf("Before: %+v\n", p)
    err = bson.Unmarshal(dta, p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("After: %+v\n", p)
}
```

Output:

```
Before: &{Name: unexpInt:12 unexpPoint:0xf84005f500}
After: &{Name:ANisus unexpInt:0 unexpPoint:<nil>}
```

Comment: I don't think bson is setting the fields to their zero value. It uses reflection and in Go unexported fields are not settable using reflection. I'm betting instead it's replacing the *Player with a whole new Player struct instead which results in the unexported fields being set to zero values. I doubt there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: In my example, I only pass the pointer to `bson.Unmarshal`. How can I get a new Player struct back when it still points to the same memory address?

Comment: [`Marshal()`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Marshal) and [`Unmarshal()`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Unmarshal) return errors, you should check them!!

Comment: @Tom I just removed the checks in this examples to make it easier to read as both calls return no (<nil>) error. But I agree, always check in real code (and to highlight that no error actually has been returned, I edited the post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  As you can see [in the source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/219/bson/decode.go#L184), `struct` values are explicitly being set to their zero value before filling in any fields.

There is no option to disable this behaviour.  It is presumably in place to make sure the result of `Unmarshal()` only depends on the BSON data and not any prior state.

Comment: True you are. I was, like Jeremy wall, of the impression that unexported fields can't be changed: "[A Value can be changed only if it is addressable and was not obtained by the use of unexported struct fields.](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet)". But yet you can set an entire struct to Zero it seems. Good to know!